# JComboBox Listener

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the functionality of the buttons according to a `JComboBox`.

For example when I choose singular and plural nouns, buttons behavior should change to this Item, and when I choose another item from `JComboBox` buttons behavior of buttons should change accordingly.

Comment: Maybe [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) will help...

Comment: Action listeners are one of the first things that you learn when starting to work on GUI. If you are using a builder for your GUI, you can attach an action listener with just a few clicks..

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to your combo box:

```
//In your class
comboList.addActionListener(this);
```

Then in ActionPerformed you can change the listener of the button of the desired functionality:

```
//In your class
JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button1");

--------------------------------------------------------

// Your actionPerformed for combo box listener
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String itemName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        if(itemName.equals("str"){

           //checking if you are not adding listener twice
           if(btn1.getActionListeners().length > 0){
                //remove all the existing listener, iterate and remove if more than one
                btn1.removeActionListener(existingListener);                    
           }
           btn1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener1());
        }
        if(itemName.equals("str2"){
           //follow same process as for above if
        }
    }
```